# The build tools for v140 cannot be found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, build-tools

I wrote a solution with Visual Studio 2015.

I copied the solution to a PC which has only Visual Studio 2013.

In the `Project Properties` I have changed the `Platform Toolset` to Visual Studio 2013 (v120).

The error still remains and I am not able to compile the project. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on your description, I do the following steps and try to reproduce your issue on our side.
1. Create a c++ console application with visual studio 2015.
2. Change a machine which has only visual studio 2013 and open the c++ console application.
3. change the Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2013 (v120).
4. Build the project.
It works fine, I could not encounter issue you occurring.  Could you please provide a simple demo with the issue via OneDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If msbuild still complains about v140, this likely means v140 is still in the project file - which you can verify with a text editor.
Are you sure you changed the toolset for *all* platform/configuration combinations? For instance if you just open the settings dialog and it happens to be showing properties for Debug|Win32 and you change one of those, but then you build Release|Win32, the latter combination will still use v140. Open the proprties dialog again and verify all platforms and configurations use the correct toolset. Or use find/replace from v140 -> v120 in a text editor

Comment: I am pretty sure that i changed for all configurations. I will check using a text editor

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The text editor option worked for me. I just opened project file with text editor and renames all v140 to v120.